# How to know which fingers to use to play songs?

Tags: piano, keyboard

It's so hard to find a good tutorial these days. Everyone is just focusing on the sheets or sequence of ABCD's to go in sequence, but no one seems to teach which fingers to use to play the appropriate chords and scales. For example, I understand how to play the C-Major scale. But I don't know how to play any of the other scales, whether major or minor. I know which keys to press, but when exactly and with which finger, I don't know.

I have a 61 key electronic keyboard(normal size, takes up a regular size table completely) and I'm looking to learn through sheets.

Anyone know of any good resources I can use? I'm looking for standard stuff, not simplified bits of 'here's how to play this piece'. However, I'm a beginner, so a comprehensive one would be nice.

Comment: The google search results for 'scale fingering' would seem to provide what you seek.

Comment: But then, how do I find out which fingers to use to play songs such as Fur Elise? I tried to play it on my own, but the finger movements of mine and a guy's on Youtube were very different.

Comment: Associated Board of the Royal School of Music publishes a large book dedicated to scales and arpeggios, along with the fingerings. Basically, there is no absolute fingering, just suggested and recommended, as each scale can be fingered in different ways (well, most), and a lot of players work out their own, using logic.

Comment: You're asking a lot to have fingerings for different pieces, ot even one specific. Part of the fun of learning by yourself is working out ergonomic fingerings. A teacher will always be a better option.

Comment: I'm just looking for a guideline - like they say when you're learning to type - always return to the home row, practice reaches, etc. Rest of the things the person figures out by himself - ideally you have to return to d when you are pressing c and also when pressing e. But in reality when typing 'access' you go directly from d to c, press c twice, then directly to e, then back to d.

Comment: Sheet music meant for teaching, like Suzuki method books to name just one obvious example, often have many suggested fingerings. Beyond that it's usually a matter of teacher suggestions, personal preference, and experience. Probably one of the most common marks a pianist will make on a score is the fingering they have decided works best for them. Look for learning materials and use them as guides to work out your personal fingerings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no simple and general guideline that I know of, except to use the fingering that works best for you. Of course that's not much help if you don't know where to start.

Traditionally, you learn by studying fingered scores from easy pieces and instrument method books. Look for a beginners book with fingering indications, like suggested by Todd, and work on the pieces. When the time comes, look for more difficult pieces with fingering indications, there's plenty e.g. on [Petrucci Music Library](http://www.imslp.org).

Also, as Tim already pointed out, studying scales and arpeggios by a good reference book with fingering notation is fundamental, but if you find it too overbearing to study all 24 major and minor tones scales and arpeggios, work on them according to the pieces you're working on, which is always good practice anyway, i.e. to practice the scale and arpeggio of the tonality of the piece you're working on. This will give a starting point for fingering, but also "put your ear" in the tonality and facilite sight reading.

Based on the experience you build this way, working on progressively harder pieces, you will have to overcome each new situation on a case by case basis, experimenting and finding what works best. A good teacher, as Tim also pointed out, makes all the difference, but if you're on a path to self learning you can always come here and ask for help for specific situations.